# Publish open graph story in facebook using ruby (fb_graph)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I use `fb_graph` to create a post in facebook account. It works fine.

```
 me = FbGraph::User.me(session[:fb_token])
 me.feed!( :message => 'This is test message', :link => 'http://site.com', :name => 'Sports', :description => "Manish placed a bet on India vs England on Sports.com")
```

But Now, I need to post a story in facebook using `fb_graph` API. Can any buddy help!

Like in iOs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/

and in ruby gem `fb_graph` I found some code related with Story:
https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/search?q=story&ref=cmdform

It means `fb_graph` should support `open-graph` story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's given in their wiki

```
# Publish an activity
action = me.og_action!(
  app.og_action(:custom_action), # or simply "APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION" as String
  :custom_object => 'http://samples.ogp.me/264755040233381'
)
```

https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/OpenGraph